# c# Determine how many hours in a time period fall within specific hours

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I have a time period of an incident (e.g. 06 April 2014 at 11:30 until 08 April 2014 at 10:15) and I have office opening hours (e.g. 9:00 to 17:00 Monday to Friday).

I need to calculate the number of opening hours (as a decimal) that were affected by the incident.

I can think of a way I can do this but it seems very lengthy and messy so wanted to see if anyone could come up with something elegant?

Thanks
Kev

Comment: What about DST and timezones?

Comment: What about public holidays?

Comment: This is non trivial, you need a calendar of office hours and iteration to solve this. Further compounded if the office is open when switching to or from Daylight Saving Time. Unlikely but possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short and readable approach using LINQ. Note that it's neither tested sufficiently nor efficient. But maybe it's helpful anyway:

```
DateTime incidentStart = new DateTime(2014, 04, 06, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime incidentEnd = new DateTime(2014, 04, 08, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0);
int minutes =  (int)(incidentEnd - incidentStart).TotalMinutes;
TimeSpan officeOpen = TimeSpan.FromHours(9);
TimeSpan officeClosed = TimeSpan.FromHours(17);
decimal numHours = Enumerable.Range(0, minutes)
    .Select(min => incidentStart.AddMinutes(min))
    .Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday 
       &&  dt.TimeOfDay >= officeOpen && dt.TimeOfDay < officeClosed)
    .GroupBy(dt => new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, 0, 0, 0)) // round to hour
    .Count();
```

The result is 11 which seems to be correct, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you very much this is perfect for what I need.

Comment: Since the office closes at 17:00, you'd want `dt.TimeOfDay.Hours < 18`.  Otherwise, you will get a false positive for 17:01 - 17:59.

Comment: @MattJohnson: good point, however, you approach has the same issue. I've fixed it by comparing timespans instead.

Comment: Oh yeah, but you still want `<` instead of `<=`.  The office is *closed* at 17:00.  :)

Comment: @MattJohnson: i don't know his office hours, he said that it's open from 9-17 which would include 17:00 but not 17:01. I leave it in his responsibility ;)

Comment: Sure.  But the point I'm making is that in general, when a time is present (whether time-only, or date+time), you should use a half-open interval.  If you say range A is 09:00-10:00 and range B is 10:00-11:00, what range is 10:00 in?  It's not in both, it's only in range B.  However, when you have date-only ranges, such as Jan 1 - Jan 2, then it becomes fully-inclusive (2 days total).

Comment: @MattJohnson: Point taken. Better?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is accurate to the nearest second.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2014, 04, 06, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2014, 04, 08, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan StartOfDay = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0);
TimeSpan EndOfDay = new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0);            
int secondCount= 0;

while ((endDate - startDate).Minutes >= 0)
{
    if (startDate.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Monday && startDate.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Friday)
        if (startDate.TimeOfDay > StartOfDay && startDate.TimeOfDay <= EndOfDay)                        
            secondCount++;
    startDate = startDate.AddSeconds(1);
}

Console.WriteLine("Total Hours and Minutes: " + new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondCount));
```

Comment: I modified this to use timespans as I was out by an hour in my calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Non-LINQ approach, also as Tims answer, not tested. Use at your own risk

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 04, 06, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0);
var endDate = new DateTime(2014, 04, 08, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0);

var openStart = new DateTime(2014, 04, 08, 9, 0, 0);
var openEnd = new DateTime(2014, 04, 08, 17, 0, 0);;

var totalAffected = TimeSpan.Zero;
var checkDate = startDate;
while (checkDate < endDate)
{
    if (IsWorkDay(checkDate))
    {
        totalAffected = totalAffected.Add(openEnd.TimeOfDay - openStart.TimeOfDay);    
    }

    checkDate = checkDate.AddDays(1);
}

if (IsWorkDay(checkDate))
{
    if (endDate.TimeOfDay > openEnd.TimeOfDay)
    {
        totalAffected = totalAffected.Add(openEnd.TimeOfDay - openStart.TimeOfDay);
    }
    else
    {
        totalAffected = totalAffected.Add(endDate.TimeOfDay - openStart.TimeOfDay);
    }
}

double numberOfAffectedHours = totalAffected.TotalHours;

private bool IsWorkDay(DateTime day)
{
    return !(day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
}
```

Comment: Tested myself, seems to work, I've added numberOfAffectedHours for the decimal output. Perhaps that was missing? The numberOfAffectedHours is 17.25, seems about right :)

Comment: The 6th is a sunday so those hours shouldn't be included.

Comment: I didn't go with this option but it seems almost there. The result should be 17 exactly though.

Comment: Ah, I've missed the workday check. The solution is now updated. Yet the correct answer is 9.25. You were down on Sunday, so that does not count, the whole Monday (8:00), and Tuesday until 10:15 (another 1:15). So in total you were down 9:15 which in decimal is 9.25

Comment: Also, you'll probably need to modify IsWorkDay to include public hodilays and such, as @Jodrell noted